# How to access a kubernetes pod by its partial name?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I often run tasks like:

- Read the log of the service  `X` 
  or
- Attach a shell inside the service `Y`

I always use something in my history like:

```
kubectl logs `kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep <partial_name>`
```

or

```
kubectl exec -it `kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep <partial_name>` bash
```

Do you know if `kubectl` has already something in place for this? Or should I create my own set of aliases?

Comment: so, `kubectl` does not have anything such, I personally use `| grep` which is bash command on the result to filter out. and do with all bash stuff.
although If you use zsh, here is on plugin that might be usefull for you: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/kubectl/kubectl.plugin.zsh

Comment: If you are fine with all the pods with in a label you can use label. `kubectl logs -l name=myLabel`

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes instances are loosely coupled by the means of **labels** (key-value pairs). Because of that Kubernetes provides various functionalities that can help you to operate on sets of objects based on labels.

In case you have several pods of the same service good chances that they are managed by some ReplicaSet with the use of some specific label. You should see it if you run:

```
kubectl get pods --show-labels
```

Now for aggregating logs for instance you could use label selector like:

```
kubectl logs -l key=value
```

For more info please see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/ .

Answer (score 2):

added to my `.zshconfig`

```
sshpod () {
  kubectl exec --stdin --tty `kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep ${1} | head -n 1` -- /bin/bash
}
```

usage

`sshpod podname`

this

1. finds all pods
2. greps needed name
3. picks the first
4. sshs into the pod

Answer (score 2):

You can go access a pod by its deployment/service/etc:

```
kubectl exec -it svc/foo -- bash
kubectl exec -it deployment/bar -- bash
```

Kubernetes will pick a pod that matches the criteria and send you to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable shell autocompletion. Kubectl provides this support for Bash and Zsh which will save you a lot of typing (you will use TAB to get the suggestion/completion).

Kuberentes documentations has a great set of information about how to enable autocompletion under [Optional kubectl configurations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#optional-kubectl-configurations).  It covers Bash on Linux, Bash on MacOS and Zsh.